# How to rerun past DAG runs after making changes

Tags: python, airflow, etl, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have an Airflow task that runs daily for the past year or so. After making some changes to the DAG, I would like to rerun based on the new code -- the UI still detects it as the same tasks that has successfully ran, even though they are different now.

Manually going to each DAG to clear all > run seems counterintuitive and there are hundreds (even thousands) of runs, is there a way I can make them all run again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Airflow doesn't reset task instance statuses after they have been completed if there is a code change. You could however give the task a new name and then set the DAG Runs to running state.

### Option 1 - User Interface

Airflow can clear the state of tasks within the UI - just use "Browse -> Task Instances". There you can:

- Create filter to select the specific task instances, i.e. by filtering for a task/DAG name and a time frame, then "Apply" the filter
- You can then see a table with all the task runs that apply to this filter, you can select all and and choose "With selected -> clear"
  [image: Airflow Task Instance UI]

### Option 2 - Command Line

Use [`airflow clear`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/cli-ref#clear):

> Clear a set of task instance, as if they never ran
> For example:

```
airflow clear -s <start_date> -e <end_date> -t task_to_reset <DAG_NAME>
```